# Can somebody reset my phone without opening screen lock?

Tags: lock-screens, factory-reset, frp

Suppose somebody took my phone and **reset** the phone ( all files will be deleted like **factory reset** ) without knowing my screen lock **password** or even opening my phone.
Is that possible? if possible then how can i **prevent** that technically?

Comment: You cannot prevent that. Only your device vendor can. All you can do is to keep backups of important files.

Comment: it is possible to create custom ROM with user-settable root of trust that can run on locked bootloader. but even if you disable recovery and download mode still attacker can flash stock ROM in EDL/bootrom mode or erase data via JTAG